# onItemClick doesnt work in a listview in a fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, onitemclicklistener, onitemclick

so, i working on a listview in a fragment...
the "onItemClick" doesnt work, but the onItemLongClick and the refresh works well..
(using SherlockLibary...)
here is my code:

```
     public static class  MyListActivity extends SherlockListFragment
        implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener,    AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener,OnRefreshListener {

    ArrayList<article> items2;
    private String[] articles = {"x","y","z"};    //articles titles

    private String[] Dates = {"20:12"
            , "18:20"
            , "15:15"
            , "14:11"
            , "10:00"
    };    //articles dates
    private Site[] Sites = {
            Site.Ynet
            , Site.bla
            , Site.blabla
            , Site.blablabla
            , Site.blablabla
    };    //articles Gender


    private void initData() {
        items2 = new ArrayList<article>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            items2.add(new article(articles[i], Dates[i], Sites[i]));
        }
    }

    private PullToRefreshLayout mPullToRefreshLayout;
    ListView list;
    MyArrayAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);
        mPullToRefreshLayout = (PullToRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.listlay);
        ActionBarPullToRefresh.from(getActivity())
                .allChildrenArePullable()
                .listener(this)
                .setup(mPullToRefreshLayout);

        initData();
        list = (ListView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        adapter = new MyArrayAdapter(getActivity(), items2);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        list.setOnItemLongClickListener(this);
        return view;
    }



    // Handle click on an item (displays it in a Toast)
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        items2.remove(position);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "select: " + items2.get(position).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    // Handle a long click on an item (deletes it)
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                   int position, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                "del: " + items2.get(position).toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        items2.remove(position);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // Update the ListView

        return true;  // i.e. all ended well
    }

    @Override
    public void onRefreshStarted(View view) {

        /**
           nathing here yet...
         * Simulate Refresh with 4 seconds sleep
         */

        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(Constants.SIMULATED_REFRESH_LENGTH);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);

                // Notify PullToRefreshLayout that the refresh has finished
                mPullToRefreshLayout.setRefreshComplete();
            }
        }.execute();

    }
}
```

any idea what can i do with it?
i tried a lot but nathing works.... help please....

i tried the to add list.setItemsCanFocus(false); or android:focusable="false"
or a ndroid:clickable="false" ...
doesnt work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onItemClick()` method won't work if the items of `ListView` is focusable. Check your item xml to see if you have set these for any of its element.

```
android:focusable="true"
```

or

```
android:clickable="true"
```

**Another soulution: Use this line**

```
list.setItemsCanFocus(false);
```

after

```
list = (ListView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

Comment: i havent set them, 
my xml:
<uk.co.senab.actionbarpulltorefresh.extras.actionbarsherlock.PullToRefreshLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/listlay"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:layout_height="363dp" >
</ListView>
</uk.co.senab.actionbarpulltorefresh.extras.actionbarsherlock.PullToRefreshLayout>

Comment: even when i set
 android:focusable="false"
and
android:clickable="false" 
that doesnt works..

Comment: Not in the listview. Check the xml of items you are adding in the list view.

Comment: no one from my XML's have any clickable or focusable...
any another idea? thats works before i made it a fragment, when that was a normal activity thats work..
(sorry for bad Grammer)

Comment: Your list view items xml shouldn't have `android:focusable="true"` or `android:clickable="true"`. Also list view shouldn't have `android:clickable="false"` or `android:focusable="false"`. Can you verify it?

Comment: i checked all of them, no one have it.